# How to get an icon from a file and ,then ,set it to a created shortcut?

Tags: c++, windows, com

**First**, I'm trying to get the icon through`SHGetFileInfo` windows function.

```
SHFILEINFO targetFileInfo;
std::memset(&targetFileInfo, 0, sizeof(targetFileInfo));

SHGetFileInfo((LPSTR) "file.txt", 0, &targetFileInfo, 
               sizeof(targetFileInfo),SHGFI_ICONLOCATION);
```

**Then**, I try to create a shortcut with the `targetFileInfo.hIcon` and the `targetFileInfo.iIcon` with a function aI wrote.

```
CreateShortcut((LPSTR)application_path,                    
                  (LPSTR)target_app_path_lnkext,                
                  (LPSTR) "Testr",                            
                  targetFileInfo.hIcon,                            
                  targetFileInfo.iIcon);
```

Inside that function I have code that looks like this:

```
// CreateShortcut 
// ...
psl->SetIconLocation((LPCSTR)hIcon, iIcon);    
// ...
```

(`psl` is a `IShellLink*`) The function runs and everything is fine. But the shortcut is created with the default icon, not with the icon I set it to use.

Comment: first argument of `SetIconLocation` must be path of the file containing the icon, but not `hIcon` of course

Comment: @RbMm yeah, I though that. But the thing is that the path is exactly what I want. There is a `IShellLink` function names `GetIconLocation` but it takes a path and an index too, so I don't thing that does what I expected it to do.

Comment: @PauRibelles What's with all the type casts? Most of them are redundant, and the others look questionable. You shouldn't be using any type casts at all. In any case, what you are asking for is not possible with this code. Like RbMm said, `SetIconLocation()` needs a file path to an icon file, but you don't have such a path available, because you are extracting a system icon from the OS, not from an icon file. You will have to save the content of `hIcon` to its own icon file first, then use the path to that file. You cannot pass an `HICON` handle to `SetIconLocation()`